# Changed my mind on a vote for a thread, do I get that vote added for the total of the day?

Tags: support, status-completed, votes

I've tried searching for something similar on the Meta, I wasn't able to locate anything.

My question is if I were to "retract" a vote from a thread that I previously voted on, does that vote now get added back to my daily total.

For example, I have 4 remaining votes for the day, I decided to retract a previous vote from a vote during the same day or from a different day. Do I receive that vote back so that now I have 4 + 1 = 5 remaining votes?

Comment: @ whyzar Did you end up asking this on Meta SE as @PolyGeo suggested?  I had a quick look but I couldn't find a question, but I am interested if there is a firm answer.

Comment: @Midavalo, haven't but I will now. I'll let you know when I hear back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the terminology of "thread", which is suitable for discussion forums, is out of place at Stack Exchange sites and, in the case you cite, should be replaced by "post" (i.e. question or answer), or by "Q&A" if you are talking about them together.

That aside, I just searched [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) and cannot locate an answer to your question.

I *think* the retraction of a vote on a post (unless done almost immediately, within 5 mins, I think) will not remove one from your daily count, and in fact may even add one by counting as another "vote" that you have performed.

If you want to be sure, I recommend that you ask this question on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) because it will apply to all SE sites and not just here at GIS SE.  If you wanted me to migrate it there, then I would have been happy to do that but now that it is more than 60 days old I will not be able to.